# How to use Service Accounts OAuth 2.0 flow with GroupsSettings-api

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

Using google-api-java-client at this [page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) we can read about some flows.

The service accounts flow works fine with calendar api:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId("[[]]")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12")).build();
```

But we have always:

```
503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
```

if we use `GroupssettingsScopes.APPS_GROUPS_SETTINGS` (the api console grant access for this requests).

We have to use a mechanism near at the old 2 legged OAuth 1.0a for manage the groups of a GApps account.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With the Groups Settings API, you will need to impersonate a Google Apps user. And that user needs to be an admin.

In addition, I personnally noticed that it is better to provide the service account id to the `setServiceAccountId()`method.

Here's what works for me :

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                .setJsonFactory(new GsonFactory())
                .setServiceAccountId("516444413363-4i0cvva2abc8a3t63bbq1a9rfqe42p70@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings"))
                .setServiceAccountUser("admin@my.doma.in")
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12")).build();
```